# MapQuest API: Any reason to use it over Google Maps?

Tags: api, google-maps, routes

So I've been looking into the different mapping API's out there, and I've narrowed it down to Google Maps API and MapQuest's API.  I'm leaning towards the MapQuest API for:

1. Unlimited queries
2. Support for draggable routes.  Google's API allows multiple way points, which is not the same thing.

The draggable routes is a pretty important feature for what I'm working on, but am I missing any big reasons to avoid MapQuest's API?  Some caveat in the EULA perhaps?  The draggable route support sucks in practice?

Comment: Lots of people use MapQuest. I still don't like their interface though so I think your question really comes down to user preference. If it makes your life easier I don't think you'll see anyone but the true elitists complain about it.

Comment: @Chuck Vose: I would've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure Google Maps doesn't support draggable routes? There are plenty of times I've accidentally dragged a planned route when using the website, throwing everything off. Not sure about the API though.

As accuracy goes I've noticed that for directions here in North Carolina, MapQuest is slightly more accurate. Google doesn't always map addresses to the right position. MapQuest and Google use different data providers in some places. Google uses a variety of data, and in some places the providers will be the same (NAVTEQ and Tele Atlas).

Otherwise it is largely user preference: I rarely do see sites though that don't use Google Maps. Microsoft seems to force their projects to use Bing for some reason ;)

Comment: Yes, Google does allow you to drag routes, including start and finish, not just the waypoints

Comment: No, Google Maps API does not support draggable routes.  As BBlake said, you can code it so that dragging the start or end point markers of a route will recalculate the directions.  But that's not the same thing as dragging the polyline onto a road you want, forcing Google to recalculate it's original directions to use the road.

Comment: I should clarify that maps.google.com supports draggable routes, but the API itself doesn't support the same feature.  Yahoo is the same way.  Seems odd they'd both leave out that one feature, and MapQuest only just started supporting it this year in their API.

Go figure.

Answer (score 5):

It's kind of a late answer, but I ended up using the [Mapquest API](http://www.widgetsandburritos.com/technical/programming/mapquest-api/) because they work better as small maps, and don't look quite as cluttered, especially after I extracted the zoom control from the map and implemented it via jQuery UI Slider.

I thought it was rather intuitive and easy to use. If I'm just looking up directions somewhere, I still always opt for Google Maps. If I need to build an API map, especially to fit smaller dimensions, MapQuest seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to actually PAY for their HTTPS services (e.g. you need to use their maps BEHIND a password protected site), it costs less with Mapquest

Comment: A LOT less. In my case MapQuest was 1/4 the price compared to Google Maps and 1/6 the price of Bing Maps.

Comment: Yes. For me it was like $3,400 annually to use mapquest vs $14,000 for gmaps.